How can I clip a Div to get the attached shapes
please anyone knows how I can clip a div to get the green shapes in the attached image, using clip-path or anything else  Attached Image here
I have tried using clip path but I am not getting the desired results. I did something like the below but can't get the rounded corners, or make it look exactly like this image
clip-path: polygon(
    50% 0%,
    68% 0,
    82% 19%,
    100% 44%,
    76% 70%,
    52% 97%,
    0 66%,
    0 52%,
    0 35%,
    0 0
  );


why not use basic css properties and no clipath? it would be far more flexible by using rotate, position: absolute and border-radius

@TanishqS Please how can I achieve that with rotate, border-radius and position

Polygons don't have curves. You need a path.

SVGs are ideal for quickly reproducing graphical elements like these. Depending on how you want this background to behave on different screen sizes, you might need to split it up into multiple parts.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.background {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: auto 95%;
<div class="background"></div>




You can use CSS's border-radius and transform properties rather than clip-path to simplify this.
Additionally, it's preferred to use pseudo-elements of CSS to get the desired shape elements
This example would help you:


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -6rem;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  position: relative;
}

.parent::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  background: #00dd8c;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parent::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 220px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  background: #00dd8c;
  top: 0;
  right: 80px;
}
<div class="parent">
</div>




It’s not very comfortable having to add to the DOM for just a visual enhancement. Have you considered using pure CSS? e.g. pseudo elements.

yea sure, since in the question he was specifically asking for a div I added that.
